# How to resolve maven problems when using dependency injection to solve circular dependency?

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies, circular-dependency

I have two classes in two different projects as follows:

Project: `projectA`
Has a class: `ProjectAClass`
pom.xml of this project has a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectA</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Project: `projectB`
Has a class: `ProjectBClass`

Now I want to use a function present in `ProjectAClass` class, but since I cannot add the dependency of `projectA` project in `projectB`'s pom.xml (as it will result in circular dependency), I am trying to use dependency injection in the following way:

I created an interface like so (in `projectA` project):

```
public interface ProjectAClassInterface {
    String funcToUse() throws Exception;
}
```

Made the `ProjectAClass` class implement the interface:

```
public class ProjectAClass implements ProjectAClassInterface{
    public String funcToUse() throws Exception {
        ...
    }
}
```

And lastly trying to use this interface in `ProjectBClass`:

```
public class ProjectBClass {
    private ProjectAClassInterface projectAClassInterface;

    public ProjectAClassInterface getProjectAClassInterface() {
        return projectAClassInterface;
    }

    public void setProjectAClassInterface(ProjectAClassInterface projectAClassInterface) {
        this.projectAClassInterface = projectAClassInterface;
    }
}
```

`ProjectAClassInterface` is coming up in RED in IntelliJ and when I click on Alt+Enter and select the option 'Add dependency on module 'projectC', I get the following message:
`Adding dependency on module 'projectC' will introduce circular dependency between modules 'projectA' and 'projectB'. Add dependency anyway?`

Despite following the interface method, I am still unable to do away with circular dependency. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: of course it comes up red. either it has a dependency on it, and thus access to the code, or it doesn't. is there a specific reason why projectA has a  dependency on projectB?

Comment: yes, projectA uses some other APIs present in projectB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a third maven module and move the interface to it. Then have your modules projectA and projectB depend on the newly created module. This will avoid the circular dependcy.

Comment: or just move the interface to projectB